# does process still continue after client disconnects

Tags: java, servlets, request

when a client disconnects from a server request prematurely, does the server still carries out rest of the work?  
specifically, in a Java Servlet doGet if I have the following code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException 
{
   A();  //client disconnects after A(); 
   B(); 
   C();  
}

if client disconnects after A() is finished, would B and C still get executed?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If during `A()` (or any other method) you would attempt to send the response (using `res`) back to the client, `IOException` would be thrown. If not caught, it would terminate the servlet execution.

Otherwise the calculation would carry on and exit after `C()`.

Comment: This may actually not be true in all cases. The response may be buffered and therefore only when the buffer is flushed you will get the exception. The other possibility is a proxy server in between, which may wait up until the whole response is sent from the server and then try to send it to the client.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it would. The server does not know about the disconnection up until it tries to write sth to the output stream (as a response). Event then due to a proxy server in between or because of output stream buffering it may be hard to know that a client disconnected.